MySQL master-slave replication with SSL: got error certificate verfication failed
Last_IO_Error: Error connecting to source 'repl@mysql-master:3306'. This was attempt 1/86400, with a delay of 60 seconds between attempts. Message: SSL connection error: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed

Above is the error message I got when I tried to connect slave with master.
I used openssl to create ca-cert.pem, master-cert.pem, master-key.pem, slave1-cert.pem, slave1-key.pem.
I have also ensured that ca-cert, master-cert, and slave1-cert CN name are all totally different:
bash-5.1# openssl x509 -in /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem -text -noout | grep -i subject
        Subject: CN = MySQL_CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
bash-5.1# openssl x509 -in /etc/mysql/ssl/master-cert.pem -text -noout | grep -i subject
        Subject: CN = mysql-master
        Subject Public Key Info:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
bash-5.1# openssl x509 -in /etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-cert.pem -text -noout | grep -i subject
        Subject: CN = mysql-slave1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:

And I tried verify the master-cert and slave1-cert, they all return OK.
bash-5.1# openssl verify -CAfile /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem /etc/mysql/ssl/master-cert.pem
/etc/mysql/ssl/master-cert.pem: OK
bash-5.1# openssl verify -CAfile /etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem /etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-cert.pem
/etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-cert.pem: OK

When I tried to do Change Master on slave1, I would then get the SSL cerification verify failed error.
CHANGE MASTER TO
    MASTER_HOST='mysql-master', -- matched the CN name as well 
    MASTER_USER='repl',
    MASTER_PASSWORD='replpassword',
    MASTER_PORT=3306,
    MASTER_LOG_FILE='binlog.000007',  -- Adjust based on master status
    MASTER_LOG_POS=157,               -- Adjust based on master status
    MASTER_SSL=1,
    MASTER_SSL_CA='/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem',
    MASTER_SSL_CERT='/etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-cert.pem',
    MASTER_SSL_KEY='/etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-key.pem',
    MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT=1;

START SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;

Any suggestions on where I missed will be highly appreciated. I have been stuck here for days : ( Thanks!!!!
Other information that might be helpful:
master's my.cnf:
[mysqld]
server-id=1
log_bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=master_db
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/master-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/master-key.pem
log-error=/var/log/mysql/master-error.log

Slave my.cnf:
[mysqld]
server-id=2
relay_log=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-slave-bin.log
read_only=1
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/slave1-key.pem
log-error=/var/log/mysql/slave1-error.log
user=mysql


Do you have the right permissions for the certs? mysql:mysql is the owner?
Take a look at this, you might be able to get an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145925/mariadb-over-ssl-not-working-certificate-verify-failed

Thank you!! after changing to mysql as the owner and rechecking my master SSL it worked

Many times i just look for the answer and don't read the commented, so i guess many others do that too, so i will also post the answer here.
The issue was with ownership. mysql:mysql should be the owner.
